# postgres: overload/add comparison operators to domain

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums, dns

I have a column which should have 3 possible values (for example 'A', 'B', 'C').
It is conventional to use enum for such kind of things, but since many tables in my DB will have such column, I would like to define a default value ('C') for type, representing this enum.

(AFAIK without any additional definitions, I need to write something like this:

`%COLUMN% %ENUM_TYPE% NOT NULL DEFAULT enum_first(null::%ENUM_TYPE%),`

every time i need such enum)

`CREATE TYPE ...` statement does not allow to define default value, but `CREATE DOMAIN ...` does.

I tried a little trick: `CREATE TYPE zzz_enum AS ENUM (...); CREATE DOMAIN zzz AS zzz_enum DEFAULT 'A';`, but query with comparison of `%zzz column% = 'A'` results in error:

`... operator %zzz% = undefined ...`

How can I define comparison operator for domain 'by-hand' or create a custom type, which will:

- Have a list of possible values, which I could get through query
- Have one of those values as a default value
- Be a identifier, which I could use like any regular SQL type in table definition

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to work, but it doesn't.  I think it's a bug.

Follow the discussion here: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2011-01/msg00082.php

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION zzz_like (a zzz_enum, b TEXT) RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS
$$
        SELECT  $1::TEXT LIKE $2;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql'

CREATE OPERATOR ~~ (LEFTARG=zzz_enum, RIGHTARG=TEXT, PROCEDURE=zzz_like)

SELECT  *
FROM    zzz_test
WHERE   zzz_column LIKE '%A%'
```

You may just cast the expression to `TEXT` right in your query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    zzz_test
WHERE   zzz_column::TEXT LIKE '%A%'
```

**Update:**

Sorry, got the problem wrong.

As @Peter mentioned, it's a bug indeed, since domains over complex types like `array` and `enum` are not implicitly cast into `anyarray` and `anyenum` required for the corresponding equality operators.

Comment: You have misunderstood the question.  It's not looking for `LIKE` functionality.

Comment: @Peter: oh, you're right. It should be a bug indeed, probably has to deal with this: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2008-01/msg00030.php

Comment: So the answer is - I can't do something like this? `LIKE` will be too slow for my purpose, I guess. Thanks anyway)